# JTA Transaction and thread

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, transactions, jta

I want to do a multi-threadable treatement with JTA.

Environment :

- JBOSS AS 6.3
- Java 7
- Oracle 11.2g
- CDI

Treatment : I want to produce a zip with all datas from database. This zip file can be big, so I want to start a thread to produce the stream in same time that jboss send it to the client.

My REST entry :

```
@Stateless
@Path("/exportProcess")
public class ExportProcessusResource {

    @Inject
    private IExport export;

    @GET
    @Path("/{processCode: [^/]+}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response export(@PathParam("processCode") final String pProcessCode) {
        return Response.ok(export.export(pProcessCode))
                                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pCodeProcessus + ".zip")
                                .build();
    }
}
```

My MODEL :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PROCESS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Process.GetByCode", query = "SELECT p FROM Process p WHERE p.code=:code")
})
public class Process {

    @Column(name = "CODE", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "process", targetEntity = Step.class)
    private Collection<Step> steps;

    //Getters/Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_STEP")
public class STEP {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_STEP")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ_ID_STEP")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ID_STEP", sequenceName = "SEQ_ID_STEP")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Process.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_PROCESS", referencedColumnName = "CODE", nullable = false)
    private Process process;

    //Getters/Setters
}
```

My DAO :

```
public interface IProcessDao {

    Processus getByCode(final String pCode);
}

public class ProcessDao implements IProcessDao {

    @Override
    public Processus getByCode(final String pCode) {
        Processus lResult = null;
        try {
            final TypedQuery<Processus> lRequest = pEm.createNamedQuery("Process.GetByCode", Process.class);
            lRequest.setParameter("code", pCode);
            lResult = lRequest.getSingleResult();
        } catch (final NoResultException e) {
            // Return null
            lResult = null;
        }
        return lResult;
    }
}
```

My Controller :

```
public interface IExport {

    /**
     * Generate export
     * 
     * @param pProcessCode Process code
     * @return Datas
     */
    InputStream export(final String pProcessCode);
}


public class Export implements IExport {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="authorizations")
    private EntityManager entityManagerAuthorizations;

    @Inject
    private ExportThreadHelper exportThreadHelper;

    @Override
    public InputStream export(final String pProcessCode) {
        //Check if user has the profile. Use database "AUTHORIZATIONS"
        checkProfil(entityManagerAuthorizations, Profiles.ADMIN);

        final PipedInputStream lInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
        OutputStream lOutputStream = null;
        try {
            lOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("d:/test.zip");// new
                                                                // PipedOutputStream(lInputStream);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot start zip generation", e);
        }

        final ZipOutputStream lZipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(lOutputStream);

        final Runnable lRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    exportThreadHelper.export(pProcessCode, lZipOutputStream);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(lZipOutputStream);
                }
            }
        };
        //To execute in same thread :
        //lRunnable.run();

        //To execute in another thread
        final Thread lThread = new Thread(lRunnable);
        lThread.start();
        try {
            lThread.join();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }


        try {
            return new FileInputStream("d:/test.zip");
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        return lInputStream;
    }
}


public class ExportThreadHelper {

    private class ProcessToExport {
        //...
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    @Named("Application")
    private EntityManager entityManagerThreadable;

    @Inject
    private IProcessDao processDao;

    public void export(final String pProcesssCode, final ZipOutputStream pZipOutputStream)
                    throws MyWayBusinessException {
        try {

            final ProcessToExport lProcessToExport = new ProcessToExport();

            transaction(entityManagerThreadable, new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void execute() {
                    final Process lProcess = processDao.getByCode(pProcesssCode);
                    for (final Step lStep : lProcess.getSteps()) {
                        //Many things
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });

            //MANY OTHER TREATMENTS

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot generate export", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    protected <T> T transaction(final EntityManager pEntityManager, final Callable<T> pCallable) {
        //I've tried with and without the annotation and with and without the "UserTransaction"
        try {
            final UserTransaction tx = com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction.userTransaction();
            try {
                tx.begin();
                final T lResultat = pCallable.execute();
                tx.commit();
                return lResultat;
            } catch (final Throwable e) {
                tx.rollback();
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
    <persistence-unit name="APPLICATION" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
        <class>Processus</class>
        <class>Step</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="AUTHORIZATION" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/AUTHORIZATION</jta-data-source>
        <!-- many things... -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

(I've cleaned the code to keep only important things).

And, if i use the monothread version (lRunnable.run()) i've the zip file, but if i run the multithread version (thread.start()) (that i've blocked here to ensure for my tests that connection isn't close by parent thread, but after i will remove thread.join()) I've this exception :

> ERROR [...ExportThreadHelper] (Thread-115) failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: .steps, could not initialize proxy - no Session:
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: .steps, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>     at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:569)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:188)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:548)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:126)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]  at
>   ExportThreadHelper$1.execute(ExportThreadHelper.java:101)
>   [metier-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  at
>   ExportThreadHelper$1.execute(ExportThreadHelper.java:1)
>   [metier-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  at
>   ExportThreadHelper.transaction(ExportThreadHelper.java:148)
>   [metier-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  at
>   ExportThreadHelper.export(ExportThreadHelper.java:97)
>   [metier-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  at
>   ExportMetier$1.run(ExportMetier.java:62) [metier-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]

Have you seen a problem in my code?

Comment: Do you having file named `ExportThreadHelper.java` in project, can you post that file. Specially lines near 90-150?

Comment: By first look on exception, it seems like you are trying to acces `Collection<Step>` from `Process` object out of hibernate session. Either don't close hibernate session or set `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to `private Collection<Step> steps;`

Comment: Thank for your attention


- ExportThreadHelper is into the "controller" part


- I want to keep the lazy loading because there is too datas and i don't use it in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query like this:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Process.GetByCode", query = "SELECT p FROM Process p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.steps WHERE p.code=:code")
})
```

Comment: I can also add "fetch = EAGER" on the field, but i don't want it because else we get all the time all data on each cases. I want to keep the lazy loading and use correctly transactions.

Comment: Why not having two queries instead?

Comment: I don't want to be dependant of the context. It's a big application, which works on REST. And this new REST resource must create an "export" in zip file of responses. So if you call "/rest/myResource" you get a JSON, and if you call "/rest/export" you will have a "zip file" with "/rest/myResource.json" which contains the response of the first request. It's a simple example but the problem is here : I want to call all other business methods in a thread to generate the zip file.